# Why is "occurring yearly" "anniversarius" and not "annoversarius"?

Tags: word-formation

The stem of "*annus*" (year) is "*anno-*" and not "*anni-*", so why is "*occurring each year*" "*ann**i**versarius*" and not "*ann**o**versarius*"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Latin compounds generally use the connecting vowel -i- placed between the two stems, with that -i- replacing any stem-final vowel.

This is sometimes argued to be due to analogy to i-stems, but a more parsimonious explanation is that it simply reflects regular vowel reduction.

Comment: And while the stem might be *anno-* in some modern grammars (especially if they have a diachronic or comparative slant), it absolutely would have been perceived as being *ann-*.